# Why i am getting error code failed with exit code 1 when restoring my db

Tags: postgresql

When i try to restore my postgress db , it failed with exit code 1. What is the reason. I created the backup using postgress 11 and restoring it to postgress 12.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are using PgAdmin4. You should upgrade it to the latest version (4.30) where they fixed the bug that caused it to hide the real error messages from you.  Then you can try again and show us the real errors.

Better yet, use command line tools to do it in the first place.

I you don't want to try again, you can instead look in the database servers log file to find the error messages.